# Parsing and saving multipart form data from a file using werkzeug

Tags: python, multipart, form-data, werkzeug, boundary

I have the below file that was saved from a http POST that I want to parse using Python using werkzeug parse_form_data().  Note that I am not getting it via a request, but through a file.  I cannot get the file directly from a flask request for other reasons.  Since I have been using Flask, I tried to use werkzeug to do this.  I thought I had problems with the boundary with the extraneous hyphens '--', but I am trimming everything down to the very simple format in the following test file:

Here's the file on the file system (myinputfile):

```
--806243354728155036129379
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="text.py"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

some text in a file

--806243354728155036129379
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

abcde
--806243354728155036129379
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"
123456678
--806243354728155036129379--
```

Here's the code I use:

```
from werkzeug import parse_form_data
import io

inputfile = 'myinputfile'
content_type = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=806243354728155036129379'


environ = {
    'wsgi.input': io.open(inputfile, 'rb'),
    'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
    'CONTENT_TYPE': content_type,
    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'}

stream, form, files = parse_form_data(environ, silent=False)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 92, in parse_form_data
cls, silent).parse_from_environ(environ)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 171, in parse_from_environ
content_length, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 195, in parse
content_length, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 100, in wrapper
return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 212, in _parse_multipart
form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 519, in parse
return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 406, in __init__
for key, value in mapping or ():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 517, in <genexpr>
form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == 'form')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 476, in parse_parts
for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 395, in parse_lines
self.fail('Expected boundary at start of multipart data')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 327, in fail
raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Expected boundary at start of multipart data
```

Ultimately I want to be able to save the file (which can be binary), and get the form data 'Field1' and 'Field2' from the dict.  Any ideas?  I am open to use other methods too.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I figured it out.  Initially I thought content length can be left empty.  It works by specifying the length like this:

Here's the final code I used:

```
def fileuploaded():
    import io

    # print 'request headers {}'.format(request.headers)
    rawfilename = request.headers.get('X_File')
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    print 'rawfilename = {}'.format(rawfilename)
    print 'content_type= {}'.format(content_type)

    # build the environ with the file stream
    environ = {
        'wsgi.input': io.open(rawfilename, 'rb'),
        'CONTENT_LENGTH': os.path.getsize(rawfilename),
        'CONTENT_TYPE': content_type,
        'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'}

    stream, form, files = parse_form_data(environ, silent=False)
    f = files.get('infile')
    f.save('/newfilepath/{}'.format(f.filename))
```